# Tag followed by a link confuses stackoverflow

Tags: bug, stack-overflow

I think I found a bug, although it can be circumvented quite easily and not many users will be affected.

I often use tags, instead of `bug` I write [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). Followed by a link, it won't work. If one types

```
[tag:bug] [meta stackoverflow][1]
```

it becomes:

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [meta stackoverflow][1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217674/tag-followed-by-a-link-confuses-stackoverflow)

Two spaces between the tag and the link fixes this, one can type:

```
[tag:bug]  [meta stackoverflow][1]
```

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)  [meta stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217674/tag-followed-by-a-link-confuses-stackoverflow)

Maybe this can be fixed to not confuse users (like me).